# How to have NGINX do a proxy pass for both / & /home?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I am new to NGINX concepts. I have a need to redirect my requests for both / and /home to the UI application microservice using proxy pass. The angular application appends a /home to the URL, which causes nginx to throw a 404 error. If I remove the /home in the URL and just hit ip-address/ it works.But when I give /home I get a 404 Not found error. Can someone please tell me what I need to add in my nginx.conf so that it redirects to UI application when / or /home is given in url.

I tried adding another location /home to redirect to UI application, but it didnot work.

Current nginx configuration:

```
server {
      listen 80;
      server_name default_server;
      location / {
        proxy_pass http://my-ui-app;
      }
      location /registry/v1/ {
        proxy_pass http://registry-service;
      }
      location /entry/v1/ {
        proxy_pass http://entry-service;
      }
      error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
      }
}
```

Comment: Try `rewrite ^/home/(.*)$ /$1 break;` in the `location /` block.

Comment: Hi, I have added the rewrite line in the nginx conf as below. Still I am getting 404 not found when I do a page refresh. 
      server {
      listen 80;
      server_name default_server;
      location / {
        rewrite ^/home/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://my-ui-app;
      }
      location /registry/v1/ {
        proxy_pass http://registry-service;
      }
      location /entry/v1/ {
        proxy_pass http://entry-service;
      }
      error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
      }

Comment: Check the access log to see the exact URL being requested during the page refresh. There are a number of questions on SO related to 404 responses after a page refresh.

Comment: FYI-The issue was resolved after using below rewrite in location / block.               
rewrite ^(/)home$ $1 last;